# Why does Rita Repulsa always show up with water droplets?

Tags: plot-explanation, power-rangers-2017

In Power Rangers (2017), *Rita Repulsa*, who is going to end the world,
always appears with pouring **water droplets** on victims. Why so?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, I would say it has something to do with her being underwater for millions of years. She first appeared in the actual days being fished out of the water and all. But that is only my opinion as interpreted when watching the movie.